# CSS '1px solid #000;' producing double border

Tags: css, border

I'm puzzled. I swear I have used this CSS before and it produced a 1px border without problems.

The CSS is:

```
#menu-primary-menu-1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;   
}
```

It is being applied around the top navigation of [this page](http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/).

However, it is producing a double-border.

[image]

I can see no CSS being applied here which is producing this double border. Can you?

Comment: Your `.header-center nav` also has a 1px border black. Thus you get two black borders.

Comment: Are you sure that CSS rule alone is producing both borders? In other words, if you remove just that rule, do both borders disappear? If so, chances are you have two elements sharing the same ID.

Comment: your header and menu both have borders that's why you are getting 2 borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this border

```
.header-center nav{
    border: 1px solid #000; /**Remove this border**/
}
```